# How to remove HTML tags from python strings?

Tags: python, regex

I have string like this:

```
<h2 class="debateHeaderProp">This house believes that society benefits when we share personal information online.</h2>
```

what's the best way to remove anything between "<" and ">" and only left "This house believes that society benefits when we share personal information online"?

Comment: "Best" depends on what you want -- if you want *robust*, you'll use a real HTML parser. If you want "short to write, no dependencies, and OK if it has wrong output sometimes"... well, is that really "best"?

Comment: What if your string has HTML entities like `&amp;`, `&gt;`, `&lt;`, etc -- do you need those to be removed (or, rather, replaced with `&`, `>`, `<`, etc), too? If so, you're getting out of regex territory and into real-parser territory. Fortunately, there are some really great HTML parsers available for Python.

Comment: Quick & dirty: Replace `<.*?>` with an empty string but [meh](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3764814)

Comment: are you trying to get all the text from the html or just a certain part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only one line of markup, using a dedicated parser is kind of overkill. However, for larger sets of data, using a parser like `BeautifulSoup` is the way to go. See an example below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import re

markup = """
<h2 class="debateHeaderProp">This house believes that society benefits when we share personal information online.</h2>
<span class="debateFormat">Oregon-Oxford, Cross Examination</span>
<div class="debateAffirmSide">On the affirmative: Foo Debate Club</div>
<div class="debateOpposeSide">On the opposition: Bar Debate Club</div>
"""
soup = bsoup(markup)

# Explicitly define the tag and class.
motion = soup.find("h2", class_="debateHeaderProp").get_text()
# Or just use the class.
d_format = soup.find(class_="debateFormat").get_text()
# And even use regex for more power.
teams = [t.get_text() for t in soup.find_all("div", class_=re.compile(r".*debate.*Side.*"))]

print "Our Debate for Today"
print "Motion:", motion
print "Format:", d_format
print teams[0]
print teams[1]

# Prints the following:
# Our Debate for Today
# Motion: This house believes that society benefits when we share personal information online.
# Format: Oregon-Oxford, Cross Examination
# On the affirmative: Foo Debate Club
# On the opposition: Bar Debate Club
```

One other option is using an XML parser similar to `lxml`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way (not sure if it's the "best")

```
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML
>>> s = '<h2 class="debateHeaderProp">This house believes that society benefits when we share personal information online.</h2>'
>>> x = XML(s)
>>> x.text
'This house believes that society benefits when we share personal information online.'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

> XML is an inherently hierarchical data format, and the most natural way to represent it is with a tree. ET has two classes for this purpose - [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree) represents the whole XML document as a tree, and [Element](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element) represents a single node in this tree. Interactions with the whole document (reading and writing to/from files) are usually done on the ElementTree level. Interactions with a single XML element and its sub-elements are done on the Element level.

read more in [parsing XML](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml)

also you can use regex :

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'(?<=>).*(?=<)' ,s).group(0)
'This house believes that society benefits when we share personal information online.'
```